# Remove the input highlighted box on click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, twitter-bootstrap-3, border

I tried to remove the highlighted blue box in the following picture on clicking the input. It is not working. What's wrong here?

[image]

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-v3.5.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter here" readonly>
```

In css,

```
.form-control:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: if it's bootstrap, add the relevant tag

Comment: Here it is. Missed the coding tag.

Comment: I meant if it's bootstrap, add the bootstrap tag with the version

Comment: Yep, it is added.

Comment: Yes, it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure that your style comes after your Bootstrap styles so that it overwrites them. The box-shadow is set to none. Not sure if you also wanted the blue border to be removed on focus, so I've changed that too.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  .form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
</style>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter here">
```